# C# About IEnumerable<T>.Aggregate

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I did some tests about `IList<T>.Aggregate()`, but the answer does not make sense to me.

```
List<int> Data1 = new List<int> { 1,0,0,0,0};

var result = Data1.Aggregate<int>((total, next) => total + total);
```

The result is `16`.

I expected it to be `32`.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Um... why do you think it should be 30?

Comment: var result = Data1.Aggregate(0, (total, next) => total + total);

The answer is 0 this time, i guess it because initial value for the accumulator (total) is 0, and pass total = 0 in the callback func.

Comment: You are correct.  That will completely ignore the items in the list.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Aggregate` doesn't run its callback for the first element in the list.
Rather, the first element is used as the initial value for the accumulator (`total`).
Therefore, your callback only runs four times, not five, and 2<sup>4</sup> = 16.